# authentication fails although email and password is correct

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-8

I tried to check the route, the action="login" on the form, at the controller, it all corrects. I tried different way of writing the code such as Auth::Attempt as well as auth()->attempt(). Other things I tried to have a look into is on the *User* model by using protected $guarded = [] or protected $fillable = ['name', 'email', 'password', 'username']. I tried hashing the password using the method **Hash::make** too to make sure the password for the newly created account is correct but it still not working.

My registration page works well, it redirects me to the home page. I compared it with my login page and tried tweaking it. Somehow, it still not working. Please help. I need to complete a project by next week tuesday. I'm in a very tight schedule right now.

Route code

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('home');
});

Route::get('/record', function () {
    return view('record');
});

Route::get('/profile', function () {
    return view('profile');
});

Route::get('register', [RegisterController::class, 'create'])->middleware('guest');
Route::post('register', [RegisterController::class, 'store'])->middleware('guest');

Route::get('login', [SessionsController::class, 'create'])->middleware('guest');
Route::post('session', [SessionsController::class, 'store'])->middleware('guest');

Route::post('logout', [SessionsController::class, 'destroy'])->middleware('auth');
```

SessionController page(login)

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class SessionsController extends Controller
{
    public function create()
    {
        return view('sessions.create');
    }


    public function store()
    {
        $attributes = request()->validate([
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'password' => 'required'
        ]);

        if (auth()->attempt($attributes)) {
            return redirect('/')->with('success', 'Your account has been created.');
        }

        return redirect('/')->with('errors', 'Authentication failed.');
    }

    public function destroy()
    {
        auth()->logout();

        redirect('/')->with('success', 'Goodbye');
    }
}
```

Home page

```
<x-layout>
    <div id="sidebar" class="bg-gray-100 border border-black border-opacity-5 w-96 py-8 px-8 mt-16 text-white">
        <div class="relative flex lg:inline-flex items-center border border-gray-400 rounded-l px-3 py-3 text-white">
            <form method="GET" action="/">
                <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search Staff" class="bg-transparent placeholder-gray font-semibold text-sm" value="{{ request('search') }}">
            </form>
        </div>

        <div class="relative lg:inline-flex bg-gray-100 rounded-xl">
            <x-category-dropdown />
        </div>
    </div>
</x-layout>
```

RegisterController

```
 <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{
    public function create()
    {
        return view('register.create');
    }

    public function store()
    {
        $attributes = request()->validate([
            'name' => 'required|max:255',
        'username' => 'required|min:3|max:255|unique:users,username',
            'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users,email',
            'password' => 'required|min:7|max:255',
        ]);

       $attributes['password'] = Hash::make($attributes['password']);

        $user = User::create($attributes);

        auth()->login($user);

        return redirect('/')->with('success', 'Your account has been created.');
    }
}
```

Login form

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Attendance Management System</title>
    <!-- CSRF Token -->
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^2/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/alpinejs/alpine@v2.x.x/dist/alpine.min.js" defer></script>
</head>


<section class="px-6 py-8">
    <main class="max-w-lg mx-auto mt-10 bg-gray-100 border border-gray-200 p-6 rounded-xl">
        <h1 class="text-center font-bold text-xl">Log In!</h1>

        <form method="POST" action="/session" class="mt-10">
            @csrf

            <div class="mb-6">
                <label class="block mb-2 uppercase font-bold text-sm text-gray-700" for="email">
                    Email
                </label>

                <input class="border border-gray-400 p-2 w-full" type="email" name="email" id="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required>

                @error('email')
                <p class="text-red-500 text-sm mt-2">{{ $message }}</p>
                @enderror
            </div>

            <div class="mb-6">
                <label class="block mb-2 uppercase font-bold text-sm text-gray-700" for="password">
                    Password
                </label>

                <input class="border border-gray-400 p-2 w-full" type="password" name="password" id="password" required>

                @error('password')
                <p class="text-red-500 text-sm mt-1">{{ $message }}</p>
                @enderror
            </div>

            <div>
                <button type="submit" class="bg-blue-400 text-white rounded py-2 px-4 hover:bg-blue-500">
                    Submit
                </button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </main>
</section>
```

Comment: What does your <head> section look like?

Comment: I updated it at the post above, have a look

Comment: We need to see your RegisterController logic.

Comment: Can you show your login form?

Comment: @Mr.Lister I updated the login form on the post above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You’re not hashing the user password when creating a new user. The Auth::Attempt() function takes the plaintext password you provide and does a Hash::make() call on it.

So when you’re logging in, it’s taking the plaintext password, hashing it and comparing it to the value in the database which is plaintext.

So, when creating your user, hash the password value before passing it to the creat function. After you’ve validated your input hash the password and add it back to your $attributes:

```
$attributes[‘password’] = Hash::make($attributes[‘password’]);

$user = User::create($attributes);
```

Comment: I wrote a new function in User model for hashing the password, public function setPasswordAttribute($password)
     {
         $this->attributes['password'] = bcrypt($password);
     }

Comment: I tried the method that you suggest above. I cancelled out the function in the User model  and include the piece of code above. But still after login, it still redirect me to the 'else' redirect and not the first 'if'

Comment: @jabs93 Please update your question showing how you’ve implemented the above.

Comment: I've updated the question and the code

Comment: @jabs93 No, you’ve not done what I said. You want to hash the password when you create the user, not when authenticating. The hashing is done automatically by the attempt() function on the Auth facade.

Comment: Mann it's working now ! I did a mistake instead in SessionsController store function. I wrote check() instead of attempt() function. Thankss man !!